# sql count(*) query on results of another query performing multiple results

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, join, count

how to perform sql count(*) query on results of another query performing multiple results ?

I've 3 tables :--

1. user_subscribe table where I've 'user_id' and other columns.
2. user  table where we have 'user_id' & 'country_id' columns where user_id is being linked with user_subscribe table and country_id is being linked with 'country' table.

   3. country table having 'country_id' column.

I need to get total count of user_subscribe based on users (user_id) who belongs to same country.
A Help is highly appreciated as I'm being stuck on this problem from last 7 days.

Comment: ***sql count(*) query on results of another query returning multiple results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This Solution :

```
SELECT C.CountryName,Count(u.UserId) AS UserCount FROM  User_Subscribe AS us 
LEFT JOIN User AS u ON us.UserId = u.UserId
LEFT JOIN Country AS c ON u.CountryId = c.CountryId
WHERE c.CountryId = 3
GROUP BY c.CountryName
```

Comment: add where condition for that i am updating my query

Comment: Hi Kavel thanks alot for responding,
Your Query is working properly without any problem.
However, the issue is still stuck as I need to find result based on the country_id which I already have.
For Example , India has country_id = 3
So I need to find out total subscriber from 'user_subscribe' table based on 'user_id' which belongs to country_id=3 (India).

Comment: please check query now and if it work then please accept and vote answer so it also helps other

Comment: Thanks Kavel it is working perfect for us,
However I don't really think that 'group by' is necessary as per our requirement.
Cheers to you anyways.   :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(US.user_id) as country_user_subscribed
FROM user_subscribe as US
LEFT JOIN users as U ON user.id=US.user_id
LEFT JOIN countries as C on C.id=U.country_id
GROUP BY C.country_id
```